# "mptt_tags" is not registered tags - Django Erro

Tags: django, mptt

I am  having error when developing blog website.Can anyone help ?

raise TemplateSyntaxError(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'mptt_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

I have installed in settigs.py as 'mptt' also and tried rerunning the server also.but couldn't find answer.

I need to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

you should add `{% load mptt_tags %}` in top of the template